# Create News Application in Android?

Tags: android, real-time

I am new Android App Developer and I have a question:
I want to create application like a news app, that I can update all the time but i dont know how to do this..
please help me..
thanks!

Solved:
I using FireBase and this is an excellent solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not to concrete in what you mean with "realtime". 
Let me flesh out two possible scenarios (+ links to possible solutions):

1. *realtime* as in "chat realtime while the app is active": You might wanna look into e.g. [socketIO](http://socket.io/) on how to establish a "persistent" connection between client and server to distribute news.
2. *realtime* as in "send instant updates to the client (even if inactive)": I think this scenario does better fit your "news app". Implement [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) and send out messages to the clients when you have new information. The clients would then pull the new information from your server (or you could even fit your "content" into the GCM message) and do something with it (e.g. display a notification to the user "Breaking News: ...." or similar)

Answer (score 1):

Updating the app's UI is just the final part of the communication process. In order to do that, you should have a source (server-side) that sends the data over a websocket while your Android client is listening.

I suggest you to read about websockets, and then try to implement it. Ask further questions if you have any concrete problem.

Comment: There's a chat here, but you need 20 reps to use it.